# NodeJS discord bot commands getting error Cannot send an empty message

Tags: javascript, node.js, bots, discord

I am making a discord bot and one of my commands is not working. I want the bot to copy what the user said in the command but I am getting the Error: **UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 2): DiscordAPIError: Cannot send empty message**
and I also tried using console.log() but that was empty too so I know something is wrong but i'm just not sure what is.

```
case "say":
    if(!args[1] == " "|| !args[1] == ""){
    //  message.channel.sendMessage(args[1]);
      words = [];
      for(i=0;i==args.length-1;i++){
        words.append(args[i]);
      }
      var wordsString = words.join(" and ");
      console.warn("Bot said: "+wordsString);
      message.channel.sendMessage(wordsString);
    }
break;
```

Comment: (!args[1] == " "|| !args[1] == "") should be (!args[1] == " "&& !args[1] == "") so that args can't be containing just a space nor be empty, right?

Comment: `args[1].trim().length` would combine both `if`s into one. Also, what does `append` do? Not a native array function I'm familiar with...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've gotten that same error when sending a non-string message to the channel, like trying to send an `Array` or `Object`.

But, the most self-explanatory one, as is the case here, **you're trying to send an empty string to the channel.**

```
case "say":
    if (!args[1] == " " && !args[1] == "") {
      // message.channel.sendMessage(args[1]);
      let words = [];
      for (let i = 0; i == args.length - 1; i++) {
        words.append(args[i]);
      }
      var wordsString = words.join(" and ");
      console.warn("Bot said: "+ wordsString);
      message.channel.sendMessage(wordsString);
    }
break;
```

As another user pointed out, you want to leave out spaces and empty strings from your if statement. So changing `||` to `&&` will accomplish this.

**As a side note**

You never declared `i` as variable, or `words` (unless you're declaring outside the block).

Comment: @Tjtorin can you `console.log(wordsString)` and tell me the results

Comment: it just has an empty space in the console

Comment: So right there you can tell that's your problem. Your bot is trying to send back and blank message, and discord is saying "hey, you can't do that". It's hard to see what exactly you're trying to do. But obviously, when you do `words.append(args[i])` nothing is being added to your words array

Comment: The best advice I can give you - go step by step through your block of code you posted and `console.log` everything. First, what does `words` contain after your for-loop

Comment: it consoles nothing

Comment: @Tjtorin Keep working backwards and log everything. Are you even reading arguments correctly? You can read in input by checking `message.content` instead of `args`, maybe this will be easier for you?.

Comment: Ty I figured it out. I had to change the == to and <= in the for loop and take away " and " in the words.join and a few other things and now it works!

Comment: Not declaring variables wouldn't be the cause of the problem

Comment: @James Declaring variables before trying to put something in them is usually a good idea, or good practice at least :)

Comment: @23k don't disagree but your answer seemed to suggest it somehow contributed to the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Your original for loop `for(i=0;i==args.length-1;i++)` says to set i equal to 0; then as long as i equals the number of arguments in your array do the following code then increase i by one. i equals 0 so it never equals the number of arguments so therefore the code never gets ran. Just changing `for(i=0;i==args.length-1;i++)` to `for(i=0;i<args.length-1;i++)` should fix your issue